# Using C#, how do I set float on my emissive property?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D, I am attempting to set the float on the emissive property on my brake lights material - but am not having any luck.

Here is my C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BrakeLights : MonoBehaviour {

    private Renderer Brakes;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Brakes = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        Brakes.material.shader = Shader.Find("Standard");
        Brakes.material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        //Brake lights
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
            Brakes.material.SetFloat("_Emission", 1.0f);
            Debug.Log (Brakes.material.shader);
        }else{
            Brakes.material.SetFloat("_Emission", 0f);
            Debug.Log ("Brakes OFF");
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?  I am also getting no errors in the console and my debug logs are showing up at runtime when I press spacebar.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't know anything about unity but why do you use upper case when enabling the keyword and then reference it using a different case? Would it be more coherent to use the same case?

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for the reply.  Much appreciated.

So Unity3D uses all caps with an underscore as the first character when enabling keywords. For reference, here is a link to the keywords (scroll down a bit):

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MaterialsAccessingViaScript.html

I used different case for the string in the set float function mimicking what I saw here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetFloat.html

I feel like I'm so close but just not doing something right or missing a step.

Comment: @Steve Those are two **different** string-based property IDs. You'll have to take up any coherency issues with the Unity team.

Answer (score 0):

I found success using the emission color, not setting a float value for its intensity.  So for example, I would set the emissive color to black for no intensity/emission and assign red (in my case) to make the material glow red.

I also realized that I have to use a legacy shader for this to work.

Here is the code that works:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Intensity : MonoBehaviour {

    private Renderer rend;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        rend = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
        rend.material.shader = Shader.Find ("Legacy Shaders/VertexLit");
        rend.material.SetColor("_Emission", Color.black);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space)) {
            rend.material.SetColor ("_Emission", Color.red);
        } else {
            rend.material.SetColor ("_Emission", Color.black);
        }
    }
}
```